# insert menu items using ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component which takes in dynamic content. One of which should be items in a `<mat-menu>`. This sort of works, but my "external" `mat-menu-items` does not have the same `parentMenu` (it is undefined) as my "internal" `mat-menu-items` after rendering completes. This makes rendering submenus not behave as expected.

**widget.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget',
  templateUrl: './widget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget.component.scss']
})
export class WidgetComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // The matMenu all the items should be connected to
  @ViewChild('actionsMenu', {static: false}) actionsMenu: MatMenu;

  // The matMenuItem's inserted into this component externally
  @ContentChildren(MatMenuItem) menuItems: QueryList<MatMenuItem>;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // By listing out these, I find that none of them have `_parentMenu` set.
    console.log(this.menuItems);
  }
}
```

**widget.component.html**

```html
<!-- The menu trigger -->
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="actionsMenu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

<!-- The menu -->
<mat-menu #actionsMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item type="button" (click)="doStuff()">
    Standard 1
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item type="button" (click)="doSomethingElse()">
    Standard 2
  </button>

  <!-- Insert dynamic items -->
  <ng-content select="[app-widget-actions]"></ng-content>
</mat-menu>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-widget>

  <!-- Actions menu -->
  <ng-container app-widget-actions>
    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="custom">
      Custom task
    </button>
    <mat-menu #custom="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item type="button">Custom task 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item type="button">Custom task 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </ng-container>

</app-widget>
```

This will render the widget and all content fine. But the "Custom task" menu item defined in `app.component.html` will not render as a submenu (which should open to the side on hover). I would expect the above to produce the following menu structure:

```
- Menu
  |- Standard 1
  |- Standard 2
  |- Custom task
     |- Custom task 1
     |- Custom task 2
```

Instead it produces:

```
- Menu
  |- Standard 1
  |- Standard 2
  |- Custom task
```

where the "Custom task" will only react on click (like a `mat-menu` without a parent menu).

My question is; how can I render the "Actions menu" as a part of the `<mat-menu>` inside my widgets.component?

**Edit**:
By the lack of response on this issue, I take it that no one has any tips to make this work out of the box. I therefore hope that the angular team might be able to provide the functionality needed for this to work. So I created a feature request here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18123

Comment: same issue here

Comment: @Wildhammer; this post triggered an issue at the angular core team. Please check https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37319 for progress.

Comment: Same issue. Did you find a solution?